# jQuery. Zoom effect. Slider jumps when moving horizontal scroll to the right

Tags: jquery, css, slider, zooming

Good day!
I have a problem with a jquery's slider.
I'm going to change the `zoom` css parameter with a slider.
Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2bLvcnkL/)

Open it in Chrome.
Place the horizontal scroll, for exaxmple, in the middle of the scroll bar.
Begin moving the slider to the left.
As soon as the right side of the horizontal scroll meets the right side (nearby the right arrow) the slider will jump to the left.

Will anyone please explain me why does this happen and how can I fix it?
Thank you

Comment: I think you Set min to (100) and take out (position-fixed) in the css for the slider  -- http://jsfiddle.net/q2a20tx3/

Comment: The main idea is to lower the zoom parameter. Your's sollution is not for my case. Thanks

Comment: oh, ok. when zooming lower the text is uneadable so i thought whats the point of that